# Lenovo W530 freezes when closing lid (not sleeping / hibernating)

Tags: windows, windows-8, laptop, windows-8.1, lid

My Lenovo W530 running Windows 8.1 freezes when I close the lid

- it is **not** set to sleep or hibernate when closing the lid
- it does not freeze when going to sleep or hibernate via the power button (or via the OS Start -> sleep sequence)

Freeze in my case means the the screen is lit up, I cannot do anything (the mouse and keyboard is not responsive (the built-in one or a USB-attached one), the power button does not do anything the  and the only way to get off that state is a long press on the power button.

It looks like the issue is with whatever happens when the lid is closed (without sleep / hibernation). I am thinking about the fact that the screen goes blank for instance (I do not know if there are any other  actions triggered when the lid closes and when it is set to "do nothing" when closed).

I have the latest updates for the OS, I also tried the Microsoft provided and the Lenovo provided video drivers - same thing. I saw plenty of discussions on that subject when googling around but they all evolve around sleep/hibernate upon lid closure or opening.

Has anyone experienced a similar behavior and found a solution?

Comment: I have two Lenovos, one is a couple of years old Ideapad S510p and the other a brand new Flex 10.
Both have the issues you describe. I haven't had chance to test it, but it seems to me that one of the Windows updates is causing it. The newst laptop (Flex 10) is just two days old, and has only the windows updates installed. But I didn't notice if the issue appeared after upgrading to Windows 8.1 (8 was pre-installed) or with some of the later updates.

Comment: Any update on resolving this?

Comment: @kent: I did not find a solution, reinstalled Windows to "fix" the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Go to device Manager, Click on Intel HD Driver, And do one of these:
1. update the driver with search for update automatically.
2. If the above doesn't work, Click on Roll Back Driver and then check what happen.
Hope this might Help!

Comment: I doubt that graphics driver has to do something with this...